# Midi Device Retrieve the pressed notes

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, midi

I'm trying to create a plugin in java for Unity, I have already succeeded to fetch and get all connected midi devices, but now I'm stuck to get the pressed notes.

On java side I have theses classes :

```java
public class UnityMidiAndroid {
    private static UnityMidiAndroid _instance = new UnityMidiAndroid();
    private static final String LOGTAG = "UnityMidiAndroid";
    private MidiManager manager = null;
    private MidiDeviceInfo[] midiDeviceInfos;
    private MidiOutputPort midiOutputPort;
    private final UnityMidiAndroidReceiver midiReceiver;
    private MidiCallback midiCallback = null;

    private UnityMidiAndroid()
    {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Ctor Created new UnityMidiAndroid");
        midiReceiver = new UnityMidiAndroidReceiver();
    }

    public static UnityMidiAndroid getInstance()
    {
        return (_instance);
    }

    public void ctor(MidiCallback callback, Activity activity)
    {
        Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        manager = (MidiManager) context.getSystemService(MIDI_SERVICE);
        midiCallback = callback;
    }

    public String[] fetchDevices()
    {
        midiDeviceInfos = manager.getDevices();
        String[] availableDevices = new String[midiDeviceInfos.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < midiDeviceInfos.length; i++) {
            Bundle property = midiDeviceInfos[i].getProperties();
            String deviceName = property.getString(MidiDeviceInfo.PROPERTY_PRODUCT);
            if (deviceName != null)
                availableDevices[i] = deviceName;
        }
        return (availableDevices);
    }

    public void openDeviceAtIndex(int index)
    {
        if (midiDeviceInfos == null || midiDeviceInfos.length == 0)
            midiDeviceInfos = manager.getDevices();
        if (midiDeviceInfos.length == 0)
            return;
        openDevice(midiDeviceInfos[0]);
    }

    private void openDevice(MidiDeviceInfo deviceInfo)
    {
        if (deviceInfo == null)
            return;
        manager.openDevice(deviceInfo, device -> {
            if (device == null)
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "couldn't open " + deviceInfo.toString());
            else {
                midiOutputPort = device.openOutputPort(0);
                if (midiOutputPort == null)
                    Log.e(LOGTAG, "couln't open input port on " + device);
                midiOutputPort.connect(midiReceiver);
            }
        }, null);
    }

    private class UnityMidiAndroidReceiver extends MidiReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onSend(byte[] msg, int offset, int count, long timestamp) throws IOException {
            if (midiCallback == null)
                throw new IOException("midiCallback = null");
            midiCallback.MidiMessage(0, msg);
            midiReceiver.send(msg, offset, count);
        }
    }

public interface MidiCallback {
     void MidiMessage(int index, byte[] data);
}
```

On Unity side I have these classes :

```cs
public class UnityMidiAndroidCallBack : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
        public UnityMidiAndroidCallBack() : base("com.test.unitymidianrdoid.MidiCallback")
        {
            
        }
        
        public void MidiMessage(int index, byte[] data)
        {
            UnityMidiAndroidInputs.str += "NewNote__"; //static property for debug when new note is pressed
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class UnityMidiAndroid
    {
        private const string PluginName = "com.test.unitymidianrdoid.UnityMidiAndroid";
        private const string UnityPlayer = "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer";
        private static AndroidJavaClass _pluginClass;
        private static AndroidJavaObject _pluginInstance;
        private static UnityMidiAndroidCallBack _callBack;
        public UnityMidiAndroid()
        {
            _callBack = new UnityMidiAndroidCallBack();
            AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass(UnityPlayer);
            AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            PluginInstance.Call("ctor", _callBack, activity);
            PluginInstance.Call("openDeviceAtIndex", 0);
        }

        private static AndroidJavaClass PluginClass
        {
            get { return _pluginClass ??= new AndroidJavaClass(PluginName); }
        }

        private static AndroidJavaObject PluginInstance
        {
            get { return _pluginInstance ??= PluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance"); }
        }

        public string[] GetAvailableDevices()
        {
            return (PluginInstance.Call<string[]>("fetchDevices"));
        }
    }
```

The problem is (I think) the callback function is never triggered, but I don't know why..

For the moment I don't want to know which note is pressed, I just want to trigger the callback when a note is pressed

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What operating system do you need to target in your game? Windows, macOS, something else?

Comment: It's for Android